# Function to add or subtract time from datetime.datetime.now() according to users input

Tags: python

I have to create a function to calculate time. The function should be able to take in three arguments, an argument that will supply the actual amount of time, and a second argument that can take what unit of time and a third argument that will dictate if the time has to be subtracted or added current time. A user can dictate if the actual unit of time can be minutes or hours. So a function as time_calc(1, h,+) will give us an hour from now and if it is called in as time_calc(1, h,-) it will give us an hour before now. Another call to the function as time_calc(1, m,-) will calculate minutes. How can i create such a function ?

What i have so far is

```py
def time_sub_hour(difftime):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    lastHourDateTimeCompare = now - datetime.timedelta(hours=difftime)
    return lastHourDateTimeCompare.strftime('%H') + ' Hours '
print(time_sub_hour(1))
```

I expect the output as  1 hour according to what the user has provided

Comment: Putting time-zone issues aside, why would you expect 10 minutes when you explicitly return only hours?

Comment: rogan, i am trying to get minutes if the user wants the minutes and hours if the user wants to output hours. The function i created above will simply deduct hours from the time now, i want it to be flexible enough so that we can have minutes or hours and eventually add weeks or months. This is something i will have to pass to a SQL script as a variable so that we have the flexibility to calculate the time as wanted.

Answer (score 1):

To construct a one-hour period:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

To construct a 90-minute period:

```
>>> datetime.timedelta(hours=1, minutes=30)
```

To add or subtract that from an existing datetime object:

```
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 13, 13, 19, 6, 15731)
>>> period_of_time = datetime.timedelta(hours=1.5)
>>> now + period_of_time
datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 13, 14, 49, 6, 15731)
>>> now - period_of_time
datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 13, 11, 49, 6, 15731)
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the post, especially when it doesn't even ask a question.

Comment: Well, OP asks "Where can i look for examples or if this is even possible with a single function." Presumably they know, or can look up, how to handle the "write a function" part, so I just wanted to show them how to add and subtract time deltas (which, granted, can also be looked up very easily).

Comment: Ben, i need help with writing the function part as well. i am a newbie to python and i have been struggling to write this function.

Comment: Well, I just ran the snippet that you posted and it printed `"12 Hours"`. It's 1:29 where I am, so that is correct based on your code - the current hour minus a timedelta of one hour - so what part did you need help with?

Comment: Your snippet `.strftime('%H')` is why it's returning only hours, by the way. You can use `strftime('%H:%M')` if you want both hours and minutes.

Comment: Creating the actual function with the three arguments and then running the function is what i am looking for help with.

Comment: Sorry for the hang time in this @pyhelp, it took me a minute to understand your continued question. Looks like you found what you were looking for?

Comment: Ben, Thank you for the reply, i am now looking for a way to format the function so that the function take something like (+1h) or (-1h) and calculate the time accordingly, dont know how i can make it format in that way. Thanks again

Comment: Got it, so what have you tried so far? You might want to post a new question for this, btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i was looking for, i have to refine it some more to return exact numbers so if it is calculating between 4 PM( which is the time now) and 2PM(which is what we are calculating with the function) I want the function  to return 2 hours. I would also like to make it more dynamic so that we don't have to pass the "h" or "m", rather somehow figure that out when we invoke the function and do the calculations accordingly. I would appreciate any suggestions towards making the function more dynamic. Thank you for all the help.

```
#the objective is to find the difference between two times and let the 
#user dictate if they want to add or reduce from the current time
  def add_timeDiff(time, value, ch):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if ch == '+' and value =='h':
           raw_time = now + datetime.timedelta(hours=time)
           result = raw_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
        elif ch == '-' and value =='h':
            raw_time = now - datetime.timedelta(hours=time)
            result = raw_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
        return result

    print(add_timeDiff(1, 'h', '+'))
    print(add_timeDiff(1, 'h', '-'))
```